# How to set value of date-picker by using timestamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I am using a datepicker and i want to set its value using a timestamp object, its initial value is assigned using `new Date()`

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
     <DatePicker
      selected={date}
      onChange={(date) => setDate(date)} />
```

if i want to use this object as initial date for the date picker

```
timestamp: {seconds: 1627282008, nanoseconds: 285000000}
```

then how can i convert it into date. How can this object data give me the date to set in date picker.

Comment: have you tried `const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(timestamp.seconds*1000));`?

Comment: @ilkerkaran it works and you can post answer

Comment: here you go mate!

Comment: yes @ilkerkaran now you can post it as answer

Comment: I have done it, feel free to upvote and mark is as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will solve your problem;

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(timestamp.seconds*1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your aim with : `new Date(timestamp.seconds * 1000 +  timestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000000)`. So your component will be same as bellow:

```
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const timestamp = { seconds: 1627282008, nanoseconds: 285000000 };
  let timeStampInDate = new Date(timestamp.seconds * 1000 +  timestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000000);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(timeStampInDate);
  return (
        <DatePicker
              className="form-control"
              selected={startDate}
              onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
              dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
         />
  );
}
```

Here's the executable code : https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-oskar-jft1d